apply() with VLines vs HLines (holoviews)
My code:
import holoviews as hv
import numpy as np
hv.extension('bokeh')

def filter_lines(lines, x_range, y_range):
    if x_range is None or y_range is None:
        return lines
    if len(lines[x_range, y_range]) > 40:
        return lines[x_range, y_range].opts(alpha=0.0)
    return lines[x_range, y_range]
    
list_lines = np.arange(0, 300, 1)
lines = hv.VLines(list_lines)

range_stream = hv.streams.RangeXY(source=lines)
streams=[range_stream]

filtered = lines.apply(filter_lines, streams=streams)
display(filtered)

This displays the lines just fine when I scroll in enough, and my X-Axis is only 40 units, the lines will be displayed.
When I use lines = hv.HLines(list_lines) instead, the lines just never appear, no matter my view range. What is happening here? Do I need to change something specifically to make this work?


Why did you include your modified code as a screenshot?

To show that the HLines are not showing up. And without the VLines the axis was a bit scuffed
